# Ошибка CS7036. Error cs7036

Tags: c#

Не могу решить вопрос с ошибкой CS7036. Пытался без конструктора, но результат не отличается. Я понимаю что в методы должно необходимо внести аргумент(string dirWay), но пользователь сам вносит url. Просьба объяснить подробнее.

```
using System; using System.IO;

namespace Programm {
    class Programm
    {
        public string DirWay;
        public Programm(string dirWay)
            {
            DirWay = dirWay;
            }
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter URL of directory");
            RequestUrl();
            Programm p = new Programm("fg");
            p.DirDelete(); //   cs7036
            p.DiLength(); //    cs 7036
        }
        public static string RequestUrl()
        {
            string dirWay = Console.ReadLine();
            return dirWay;
        }
        public void DiLength(string dirWay)
        {
            DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(dirWay);
            FileInfo[] fileArr = dir.GetFiles();
            foreach (FileInfo f in fileArr)
            Console.WriteLine("The size of {0} is {1} bytes.", f.Name, f.Length);      
        }
        public void DirDelete(string dirWay)
        {
            
            DirectoryInfo dirInfo = null;
            try
            {
                dirInfo = new DirectoryInfo(dirWay);
                dirInfo.Delete(true);
                Console.WriteLine("Directory delete");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
        } 
    }
```

}

Comment: `RequestUrl();` -> `var requestUrl = RequestUrl();`, ну а методы `p.DirDelete(requestUrl);` и др. За вас не будут в переменные подставлять данные, вы спросили у пользователя, да, только "сунуть" это в методы забыли.

Comment: Спасибо # EvgeniyZ, помогло.